# Youtube Javascript API not allowing playback control on mobile even when initiated through user input

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, video, youtube

In the following fiddle there are external controls for the youtube player. They work fine on desktop browsers, however in a mobile browser the play button fails to start the playback of the video.

https://jsfiddle.net/wittjosiah/oLxv6ep2/

According to the Apple Developer Library:

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it. This means the JavaScript play() and load() methods are also inactive until the user initiates playback, unless the play() or load() method is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play button works, but an onLoad="play()" event does not.

However, in this scenario the `play()` method *is* user-triggered but is still failing to initiated playback on both the iPhone simulator and my iPhone 6S.

Am I missing something? Is there a reason this isn't working? Youtube's mobile site initiates playback from a user-action so it must be possible. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

YT.Player [does not guarantee](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Mobile_considerations) that playVideo() will work in all mobile environments.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the preference `MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction` to `true`